# Rename all files to uppercase in a single shell pipeline or compound command

Tags: bash, pipe, piping

I created simple bash script. But I have to use only piping and scripts  are not allowed.
Can you help me 'translate' it ? 
This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in *
do
   if [ -f "$x" ]
   then
      mv $x $(echo  $x | tr 'a'-'z' 'A'-'Z')
   fi
done
```

Comment: Take a look at Perl's `rename` command: `rename 'y/a-z/A-Z/' *`

Comment: isn't a script ? I think im close to the solution. "find . -type f -name '*' -exec mv {} -exec  $(echo {} | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' ) \;"

Comment: `if [ "$x" -f]` is not `if [ -f "$x" ]`. And you've got a bunch of bugs due to bad quoting; run your code through http://shellcheck.net/

Comment: and if your target shell is bash 4.x, you'd be better off with `mv "$x" "${x^^}"`, which doesn't need any external tools such as `tr` at all.

Comment: (And what in the world do you mean by "scripts are not allowed"? This *is* a script, after all).

Comment: Oh sorry , u are correct . I ve recnetly started learning. So, what should i do to make  "find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '*' -exec mv {} $(echo {} | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z') \;" work ?

Comment: I mean that it cannot by in some file  it has to be one command in terminal with piping.

Comment: What's the context? Is this a classroom exercise, or are these constraints somehow technical ones?

Comment: It's classroom exercise to change name for every file in this directory (not subdirectory)  replacing small letters with big ones.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have bash 4.0 or newer:

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 \
  -exec bash -c 'for arg; do [[ $arg = "${arg^^}" ]] || mv "$arg" "${arg^^}"; done' _ {} +
```